# git push files don't get updated remotely

Tags: git

A very common scenario:

We have a bare repository.
If the developers do `git push` from their local machine to the `bare` repo, and then another developer does `git pull` they get the local version of the application (files included) updated.

However, from time to time, when a change is made directly (by our host or whatever) on the `remote working tree`, we end up having different file versions on our local machines, and the `remote working tree` get's always outdated!

According to this:

https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#non-bare

> The push operation is always about propagating the repository history
>   and updating the refs, and never touches the working tree files. In
>   particular, if you push to update the branch that is checked out in a
>   remote repository the files in the work tree will not be updated.

I'm not sure what `checked out in a remote repository` means. I didn't make any `git checkout whatever` to switch branches using ssh remotely (if that's what that means).

Anyway, if we do git push, no working tree files gets touched. Ok.

So in order to solve this:

> If you are sure what you are doing, you can do a "git reset --hard" on
>   the side you pushed to. Note that this WILL lose ALL changes you made
>   on that side, resetting the working tree to the newest revision you
>   pushed.

"git reset --hard"

I did this, but nothing got changed. It says:

```
HEAD is now at 45d948a Merge branch 'dev' of /home/blabla/private/repos/blabla_hub into dev
```

But nothing is changed.

1) How does all developers have the working tree updated if they are only pushing and pulling trough a bare (no working tree) repository ? (Where do the files pass?)

2) Why didn't I get the `remote working tree` updated as expected ?

Are my questions clear? Please advice.

**UPDATE**

I'm using a dev and master branch. Both locally and remotely, apart from that, I'm using this schema:

> The key idea in this system is that the web site exists on the server
>   as a pair of repositories; a bare repository alongside a conventional
>   repository containing the live site. Two simple Git hooks link the
>   pair, automatically pushing and pulling changes between them.
>
> The two repositories:
>
> ```
> Hub is a bare repository. All other repositories will be cloned from this.
> Prime is a standard repository, the live web site is served from its working directory.
> ```
>
> Using the pair of repositories is simple and flexible. Remote clones
>   with ssh-access can update the live site with a simple git push to
>   Hub. Any files edited directly on the server are instantly mirrored
>   into Hub upon commit.

ref. http://joemaller.com/990/a-web-focused-git-workflow/

Comment: By a bare repository, it means you do not intend to do a `git checkout` on that repository directly. And the repo is just used as a remote to synchronize other repos. So I'm not sure how you're able to change your remote repo directly without a `git checkout` (which would violate the repo's bareness).

Comment: What do you mean by "remote working tree"? Please provide details about how your repos are set up. Feel free to use pseudonyms of course.

Comment: @Tuxdude - Not sure if this answers your question but: I have the site hosted on some host company. That host company as changed a .htaccess file remotely (on my project working tree, without using git to do so).

Comment: @Code-Guru - I've updated my question, perhaps it may answer your question.

Comment: I'm still unclear about your set up and workflow. You have a bare repository (call it Hub) and a repository on the webserver (call it Prime). I assume you also have your own repository (call it Mine). Now what kind of interaction causes the problem that you are asking about? I assume you make changes, commit them to Mine, and push them to Hub. Then what? Do you also push your changes to Prime? If so, you also need to update the Prime working directory as described in the quoted docs in your question.

Comment: I have a `dev` and `master` branches, locally. Remotely I have a bare repository (hub), a `dev`and `master`branches as well.So, this goes like this: On `dev` 1) we change the code; 2) we `commit -a -m` those changes; 3) we do `git push` (since we were on `dev` the remote `dev` gets updated. When all this is ok, and the `dev` finished, we then locally 4) checkout master, 5) merge dev, and push. This works fine. However, sometimes, the files on `www/dev` are directly changed by our host. And when that happens, if we do all over 1) to 3) again, the remote `dev` working tree doesn't get updated. W

Comment: What is `www/dev`? Is it another repository with a working directory?

Comment: @Code-Guru `www/dev` yes it is.

Comment: So: two main branches, one for each server. Pushing to master sends changes on to live, pushing to dev/stage (or whatever you call it) sends changes to staging. Workflow is like so:

Create branch from dev, work locally until you're ready to test, merge back to dev, push to Hub, which sends changes to dev/staging server.

Once you're ready with those to go live, merge from dev to master, then push master to Hub, which sends those changes on to the live server.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26400/discussion-between-code-guru-and-mem)

Comment: How are you talking to your remote repositories?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen do you mean, what happens under the woods when we do `git push` or pull ?

Comment: Not sure if this answers but, we are using git remote, and ssh access to make this work. (more details on the link provided on my question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you have at least three repos: `local`, `hub`, and `www/dev`. You do your work with the `local` repo (make changes, commit, and push to `hub`). Sometimes the `www` working tree is modified by the webserver. If you want to keep these changes under version control, you can commit them to the `www/dev` repo and even push the commit from `www/dev` to `hub`. (You might be able to automate this with a cron job. I suggest using the output of `git status` to determine if you want to make a commit.)

Your original question made it sound like the working copy for the `www/dev` repo gets out of sync with the `www/dev` repo itself. After further discussion in chat, it appears that the `www/dev` repo isn't always up-to-date with the `hub` repo. You just need to make sure to run `git pull` in the `www/dev` repo when necessary (possibly with a hook or some other script).